# Insert XML into an XML element

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a string containing some XML:

```
<some>
  <xml></xml>
  <tags/>

  <TheData/>

  <more>asdf</more>
  <of/>
  <them></them>
</some>
```

Instead of `<TheData/>` we could have `<TheData></TheData>` or other equivalent forms.

Questions:

1: How can I make sure that the XML does indeed contain an **empty** `TheData` element?

2: How can I insert another XML string, **HTML encoded** into `TheData`? Example of the other XML:

```
<mydata>
  <name>John</name>
  <address>New York City</address>
</mydata>
```

End result:

```
<some>
  <xml></xml>
  <tags/>

  <TheData>
    &lt;mydata&gt;
      &lt;name&gt;John&lt;/name&gt;
      &lt;address&gt;New York City&lt;/address&gt;
    &lt;/mydata&gt;
  </TheData>

  <more>asdf</more>
  <of/>
  <them></them>
</some>
```

Are there quick ways to do this with e.g. LINQ to XML?

Comment: `<TheData/>` and `<TheData></TheData>` are equivalent. You really shouldn't care which one is there.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth You're right I shouldn't care, and the solution should work no matter which of them is used.

Comment: you should read up on [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) and [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you have to load your XML into memory as an `XDocument` instance:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(yourFilePath);
```

Then, you can answer your questions:

> 1: How can I make sure that the XML does indeed contain an **empty** `TheData` element?

```
var theData = doc.Root.Element("TheData");

if(theData != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)theData))
{
    // document contains TheData element which is empty
}
```

> 2: How can I insert another XML string, **HTML encoded** into `TheData`?

```
theData.Value = @"<mydata>
                      <name>John</name>
                      <address>New York City</address>
                  </mydata>";
```

You don't have to bother about XML encoding here. `XElement` class will take care of that.

Comment: I think you mean `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(theData.Value)` or `theData == null`

Comment: @user1477388 He wants `theData.Value` to be empty, so I think my condition is correct.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Does casting it to (string) automatically give the .Value or did you forget to type .Value?

Comment: @roger.james It gives the `Value`